# network LAN ssh is running but internet can not connect

Tags: networking, server, ssh, dhcp

I have a old project to run an odroid cluster at home, thus I started configuring the network.
there is 5 Odroid XU4 with Ubuntu 22.04:
master with eth0 1Gbit/s 10.10.10.1 & eth1 100Mbit/s 192.168.1.20
then the slaves from slave1 eth0 1Gbit/s 10.10.10.2 to 10.10.10.5 for slave4.

Up to now I configured /etc/host on all.
SSH got configured for all and is running.

particularly on master I installed isc-dhcp-server and fixed eth0 MAC address and eth1 MAC address in   /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules.
The DHCP is set to authoritative without any domain-name and the subnet json code is set in
/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf.
Both eth1 and eth0 are static ip address configured in /etc/network/interfaces.
The iptable policy is ACCEPT for all chains, but are empty.

Although I can SSH to master on 192.168.1.20 and ping 192.168.1.1 my internet gateway from master, it can,t connect on http.

```
    'odroid@master:~$ ip address show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1e:06:32:a2:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.10.10.1/24 brd 10.10.10.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::21e:6ff:fe32:a233/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:18:a0:d4:e8:8e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.20/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a02:8428:3e7e:ce01:3e18:a0ff:fed4:e88e/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr 
       valid_lft 604698sec preferred_lft 604698sec
    inet6 fe80::3e18:a0ff:fed4:e88e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
odroid@master:~$ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network:0               
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 8
       bus info: usb@6:1
       logical name: eth0
       serial: 00:1e:06:32:a2:33
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.10.11 duplex=full ip=10.10.10.1 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 9
       bus info: usb@4:1.1
       logical name: eth1
       serial: 3c:18:a0:d4:e8:8e
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.10.11 duplex=full ip=192.168.1.20 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
odroid@master:~$ resolvectl status
Global
       Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (eth0)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (eth1)
Current Scopes: none
     Protocols: -DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported'
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to define the gateway to eth1 and I had to configure the nameserver 8.8.8.8 in resolv.conf.

copy past from slave to master was not a good idea.